# Поиск ближайшего значения

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

Написал код для поиска ближайшего значения к заданному, мне сказали что плохо, а собственно почему так и не ответили, может тут кто скажет.

```
static int nearest(int n, int...args)
{
    int nearest = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {   
        int r1 = 0;
        int r2 = n;

        for(int j = 0; j < args.length; j ++)
        {
        r1 = n - args[j];
        if(r1 < 0) { r1 *= -1; }

        if((r1) == 0) { nearest = args[j]; break; }
        else {  if(r2 > r1) { r2 = r1; nearest = args[j]; }   }
        }
    }

  return nearest;   
}
```

Comment: Ну... Вот зачем вам, например, внешний цикл с одной итерацией?..

Comment: `nearest( 1, 100, 200 )` вернет 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  static int nearest(int n, int...args)
    {
        //тут мы храним значение ближайшего числа
        int nearest = 0;
        //очевидно же, что максимальное значение типа int - это одновременно максимальная удаленность двух чисел
        //Умножаем на два и приводим к типу long, так как в Java нет беззнаковых типов
        long value = 2*Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        //дальше просто проходим по массиву и сравниваем разницу
        //сравнение по модулю, т.е. чем меньше разница - тем ближе числа
        for(int arg : args)
            if (value > Math.abs(n - arg)){
            value = Math.abs(n-arg);
            nearest = arg;}    

      return nearest;
    }
```

Касательно твоего способа - много лишних переменных, лишний цикл, много сравнений. Короче - много лишних операций.

Comment: Кстати, сейчас столкнулся - в java же нет беззнаковых, а значит надо брать тип, который в два раза больше int, как минимум. Максимальная разница между Integer.MAX_VALUE и Integer.MIN_VALUE равна удвоенному Integer.MAX_VALUE. Поэтому тут тип long

Comment: С лонгом правда возникли проблемы, взял просто value как int равный Integer.MAX_VALUE и тогда все начало работать без проблем;
Возможно ли что там при сравнении возникали какие либо проблемы с приведением типов или что то подобное ну а то не знаю почему не работало

Comment: Я взял лонг, так как могут передаваться отрицательные значения и тогда алгоритм неверно работает. Странно, приведение типов должно по идее сработать. Можно явно привести: long value = (long)(2*Integer.MAX_VALUE). Просто если создавать функцию, которая ищет ближайшее число и использует тот же тип, то тут несколько сложнее алгоритм, но суть такова же - просто вычисляется расстояние и сравнивается.